# Refresh Cache concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency

Suppose I have Java Bean called `MyCache` that has multiple getters and setters.
I have one instance of `MyCache` in my application. And it's a `volatile` field `myCache` in `MyCacheHolder`.
When I need to refresh `MyCache` I create a new copy of it (it takes time) and then I just assign the reference `myCache` to this new object.

Many threads are reading `MyCacheHolder#myCache` concurrently. They will definitely get the latest Reference because it's `volatile`. But I'm not sure if they get the object that is fully initialized. The object is initializes via setters. Is it possile that reading threads won't see all fields of `myCache`? If yes then how can I fix it?

Comment: If you 1) assign all values, then 2) assign the **fully initialised** `MyCache` to the `volatile` field you have no issue. If you mutate `MyCahce` in _any_ way after publishing it, then you have an issue. Given that `MyCache` is shared between multiple threads, I would put a large amount of time and effort into making `MyCahce` a **fully immutable** `class`; then there could not be any problems of stale state.

Comment: Yes, I do exactly 1) and 2), but I still afraid that some values that were set  via setters to MyCache before assigning to volatile variable could be not visible by other threads. To be visible by other threads some "happens before" rules must be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the field `myCache` `volatile` is not enough to make it thread safe, you need to make the class `MyCache` thread safe too by either synchronizing access to your getters and setters or making `MyCache` immutable (all its non static fields must be `final` and themselves immutable). For me the best solution is making the class immutable since once the instance created as its state cannot change, it can be accessed by any number of threads without the need to synchronize access to any of its fields.

Answer (score 0):

If cache object is true JavaBean (setters with one parameter) and permitted cache object state is set by calling multiple setters then synchronization **in** setters don't help.

And immutability has a contradiction with JavaBean spec.

So if you need JavaBean - synchronize in cache outer object.

If JavaBean isn't mandatory - use immutable object.